# not able to get values of Toggle switch using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

Below is my small Project which i am working on.it has two Toggle switch which displays the status of switch whether yes/no based on OnClick Function.

I Need to 
1. alert the value of the respective toggle switch 
2. display the same value in same page below under 'status'.

i have inserted console.log to check which output i am getting. 
Only first toggle switch value yes and No both are displayed properly

pl help to know what i am missing
below is my HTML CSS code

HTML:

```js
function loadNewPage()
 {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.switch-input').on('change', function() {
          var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
          var selectedData;
          var $switchLabel = $('.switch-label');
          console.log('isChecked: ' + isChecked); 

          if(isChecked) {
            selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-yes');
          } else {
            selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-no');
          }
          console.log('Selected data: ' + selectedData);
});
  });
}
```

```css
body
{
                line-height: 1.6em;
}

#box-table-a th
{
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: normal;
                padding: 8px;
                background: #b9c9fe;
                border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
                color: #039;
}
#box-table-a td
{
                font-size: 15px;padding: 8px;
                background: #e8edff; 
                border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
                color: #669;
                border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
#box-table-a tr:hover td
{
                background: #d0dafd;
                color: #339;

}


#box-table-a
{
                font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                margin-top: 45px;
                margin-bottom: 45px;
                padding:100px 2%;
                width: 580px;
                text-align: center;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
                border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
}


body {margin:0;background-size: 100% 100%;webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-moz-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:100px 2%;font:14px/24px 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000;}       
#wrapper { width: 780px; background:#FFF; margin:0 auto; margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;border:solid 0px #E7E7E7; border-top:5px solid #0088cc; 
border-bottom:5px solid #0088cc;border-radius:6px; box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9), inset 0 4px 0 #ededed }

#bkgnd {width: 1080px; background:#3DFFA3;margin:0 auto;border:solid 0px #E7E7E7;border-top:5px solid #0088cc;
;border-bottom:5px solid #0088cc;border-radius:6px;box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9), inset 0 4px 0 #ededed;}

h2 { padding:30px 20px; border-bottom:solid 1px #e0e0e0; margin-bottom:20px; text-align:center; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
span.class2 { color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold;font-family:Calibri;font-size:20;}
h2.class1 { color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:20;}

section { padding:0 20px 20px}
h3{ font:300 22px/30px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0;font-size:18px; margin:20px 0 5px 0;}
h3 span{color:#0088cc;}
    
.switch {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 100px;
                height: 30px;
                padding: 3px;
                margin:0;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
                border-radius: 18px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
                cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-input {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                opacity: 0;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                height: inherit;
                font-size: 10px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                background: #eceeef;
                border-radius: inherit;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                margin-top: -.5em;
                line-height: 1;
                -webkit-transition: inherit;
                -moz-transition: inherit;
                -o-transition: inherit;
                transition: inherit;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before {
                content: attr(data-no);
                right: 11px;
                color: #aaaaaa;
                text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
                content: attr(data-yes);
                left: 11px;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
                background: #E1B42B;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
                opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
                opacity: 1;
}
.switch-handle {
                position: absolute;
                top: 4px;
                left: 4px;
                width: 28px;
                height: 28px;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
                border-radius: 100%;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
                width: 12px;
                height: 12px;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
                border-radius: 6px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
                left: 74px;
                box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Switch Left Right
==========================*/
label {
display:inline-block;}

.switch-left-right .switch-label {
                overflow: hidden;
    
}
.switch-left-right .switch-label:before, .switch-left-right .switch-label:after {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                top: 4px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                padding: 11px 0 0 0;
                text-indent: -12px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.switch-left-right .switch-label:before {
                background: #eceeef;
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 80px;
}
.switch-left-right .switch-label:after {
                text-align: left;
                text-indent: 9px;
                background: #FF7F50;
                left: -100px;
                opacity: 1;
                width: 100%;
}
.switch-left-right .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
                opacity: 1;
                left: 100px;
}
.switch-left-right .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
                left: 0;
}
.switch-left-right .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
                background: inherit;
}

/* Transition
============================================================ */
.switch-label, .switch-handle {
                transition: All 0.3s ease;
                -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
                -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
                -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="bkgnd">
<div id="wrapper">
 <section>
  <center>
   <label><h3>Notification 1</h3>
    <label class="switch switch-left-right">
     <input class="switch-input" id="switch-input1" type="checkbox" onclick="loadNewPage();"/>
     <span class="switch-label" id="switch-label1" data-yes="YES" data-no="NO"></span><span class="switch-handle"></span>
    </label>
   </label>
   <label><h3>Notification 2</h3>
    <label class="switch switch-left-right">
    <input class="switch-input" id="switch-input2" type="checkbox" onclick="loadNewPage()";/>
    <span class="switch-label" id="switch-label2" data-yes="YES" data-no="NO"></span><span class="switch-handle"></span>
    </label>
   </label>
  </center>
 </section>
 <center>
  <table id="box-table-a">
   <thead>
    <tr style="border-left: 4px solid #aabcfe; border-right: 4px solid #aabcfe;">
     <th>Notification 1</th>
     <th>Notification 2</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr style="border-left: 4px solid #aabcfe; border-right: 4px solid #aabcfe;">
     <td>NO</td>
     <td>NO</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </center>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: in The console log i am able to get the selected Values of both the Checkbox(Toggle). but cannot identify which one is selected/not and need to display the same values in same page.

Comment: I see here `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`. Did you include Jquery?

Comment: i have included `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the script . if i save the complete code in html file i get no error as you said  but instead in this snippet i am getting error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.switch-input').on('change', function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log('Selected data: ' + (isChecked?'Yes':'NO'));
    $('td').eq($('.switch-input').index(this)).html((isChecked?'Yes':'NO'));
  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.switch-input').on('change', function() {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log('Selected data: ' + (isChecked?'Yes':'NO'));
    $('td').eq($('.switch-input').index(this)).html((isChecked?'Yes':'NO'));
  })
});
```

```css
body
{
                line-height: 1.6em;
}

#box-table-a th
{
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: normal;
                padding: 8px;
                background: #b9c9fe;
                border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
                color: #039;
}
#box-table-a td
{
                font-size: 15px;padding: 8px;
                background: #e8edff; 
                border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
                color: #669;
                border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}
#box-table-a tr:hover td
{
                background: #d0dafd;
                color: #339;

}


#box-table-a
{
                font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                margin-top: 45px;
                margin-bottom: 45px;
                padding:100px 2%;
                width: 580px;
                text-align: center;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
                border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
}


body {margin:0;background-size: 100% 100%;webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-moz-text-size-adjust:100%;padding:100px 2%;font:14px/24px 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color:#000;}       
#wrapper { width: 780px; background:#FFF; margin:0 auto; margin-top:50px;margin-bottom:50px;border:solid 0px #E7E7E7; border-top:5px solid #0088cc; 
border-bottom:5px solid #0088cc;border-radius:6px; box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9), inset 0 4px 0 #ededed }

#bkgnd {width: 1080px; background:#3DFFA3;margin:0 auto;border:solid 0px #E7E7E7;border-top:5px solid #0088cc;
;border-bottom:5px solid #0088cc;border-radius:6px;box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.9), inset 0 4px 0 #ededed;}

h2 { padding:30px 20px; border-bottom:solid 1px #e0e0e0; margin-bottom:20px; text-align:center; font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
span.class2 { color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold;font-family:Calibri;font-size:20;}
h2.class1 { color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:20;}

section { padding:0 20px 20px}
h3{ font:300 22px/30px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0;font-size:18px; margin:20px 0 5px 0;}
h3 span{color:#0088cc;}
    
.switch {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 100px;
                height: 30px;
                padding: 3px;
                margin:0;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
                border-radius: 18px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
                cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-input {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                opacity: 0;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                height: inherit;
                font-size: 10px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                background: #eceeef;
                border-radius: inherit;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                margin-top: -.5em;
                line-height: 1;
                -webkit-transition: inherit;
                -moz-transition: inherit;
                -o-transition: inherit;
                transition: inherit;
  box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before {
                content: attr(data-no);
                right: 11px;
                color: #aaaaaa;
                text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
                content: attr(data-yes);
                left: 11px;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
                opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
                background: #E1B42B;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
                opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
                opacity: 1;
}
.switch-handle {
                position: absolute;
                top: 4px;
                left: 4px;
                width: 28px;
                height: 28px;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
                border-radius: 100%;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
                width: 12px;
                height: 12px;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
                background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
                border-radius: 6px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
                left: 74px;
                box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
/* Switch Left Right
==========================*/
label {
display:inline-block;}

.switch-left-right .switch-label {
                overflow: hidden;
    
}
.switch-left-right .switch-label:before, .switch-left-right .switch-label:after {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                top: 4px;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                padding: 11px 0 0 0;
                text-indent: -12px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.switch-left-right .switch-label:before {
                background: #eceeef;
                text-align: left;
                padding-left: 80px;
}
.switch-left-right .switch-label:after {
                text-align: left;
                text-indent: 9px;
                background: #FF7F50;
                left: -100px;
                opacity: 1;
                width: 100%;
}
.switch-left-right .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
                opacity: 1;
                left: 100px;
}
.switch-left-right .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
                left: 0;
}
.switch-left-right .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
                background: inherit;
}

/* Transition
============================================================ */
.switch-label, .switch-handle {
                transition: All 0.3s ease;
                -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
                -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
                -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bkgnd">
<div id="wrapper">
  <section>
    <center>
      <label><h3>Notification 1</h3>
        <label class="switch switch-left-right">
          <input class="switch-input" id="switch-input1" type="checkbox">
          <span class="switch-label" id="switch-label1" data-yes="YES" data-no="NO"></span><span class="switch-handle"></span>
        </label>
      </label>
      <label><h3>Notification 2</h3>
        <label class="switch switch-left-right">
        <input class="switch-input" id="switch-input2" type="checkbox">
        <span class="switch-label" id="switch-label2" data-yes="YES" data-no="NO"></span><span class="switch-handle"></span>
        </label>
      </label>
    </center>
  </section>
  <center>
    <table id="box-table-a">
      <thead>
        <tr style="border-left: 4px solid #aabcfe; border-right: 4px solid #aabcfe;">
          <th>Notification 1</th>
          <th>Notification 2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr style="border-left: 4px solid #aabcfe; border-right: 4px solid #aabcfe;">
          <td>NO</td>
          <td>NO</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </center>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I didn't got the logic of attaching function to `click` and then listening for the `change` event.

I have removed that code, and in my code, I am just listening for the `change` function.
Also for `switchLabel`, you were selecting using the `.switch-label`, which will select both the labels.

To select the label of input box, which was clicked, I have used the `next` property.

To change the status inside the table, you can find out which switch was selected by using `e.target.id`. Then you can update the table accordingly.

```js
$('.switch-input').on('change', function(e) {

  var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
  var selectedData;
  var $switchLabel = $('this').next('span');
  var statusTD;
  if(e.target.id === "switch-input1") {
    statusTD = $("#status-1");
  } else {
    statusTD = $("#status-2");
  }
  
  
  if (isChecked) {
    selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-yes');
    statusTD.text("Yes");
  } else {
    selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-no');
    statusTD.text("No");
  }
  
  
});
```

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

#box-table-a th {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #b9c9fe;
  border-top: 4px solid #aabcfe;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #039;
}

#box-table-a td {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px;
  background: #e8edff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #669;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#box-table-a tr:hover td {
  background: #d0dafd;
  color: #339;
}

#box-table-a {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  padding: 100px 2%;
  width: 580px;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-top: 7px solid #9baff1;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #9baff1;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  padding: 100px 2%;
  font: 14px/24px 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 780px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: solid 0px #E7E7E7;
  border-top: 5px solid #0088cc;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #0088cc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), inset 0 4px 0 #ededed
}

#bkgnd {
  width: 1080px;
  background: #3DFFA3;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: solid 0px #E7E7E7;
  border-top: 5px solid #0088cc;
  ;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #0088cc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), inset 0 4px 0 #ededed;
}

h2 {
  padding: 30px 20px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #e0e0e0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

span.class2 {
  color: #4C4C4C;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 20;
}

h2.class1 {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 20;
}

section {
  padding: 0 20px 20px
}

h3 {
  font: 300 22px/30px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
}

h3 span {
  color: #0088cc;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-no);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-yes);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #E1B42B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 74px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Switch Left Right
==========================*/

label {
  display: inline-block;
}

.switch-left-right .switch-label {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-left-right .switch-label:before,
.switch-left-right .switch-label:after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 11px 0 0 0;
  text-indent: -12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.switch-left-right .switch-label:before {
  background: #eceeef;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 80px;
}

.switch-left-right .switch-label:after {
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 9px;
  background: #FF7F50;
  left: -100px;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.switch-left-right .switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 100px;
}

.switch-left-right .switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  left: 0;
}

.switch-left-right .switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: inherit;
}


/* Transition
============================================================ */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bkgnd">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <section>
        <center>
          <label><h3>Notification 1</h3>
    <label class="switch switch-left-right">
     <input class="switch-input" id="switch-input1" type="checkbox"/>
     <span class="switch-label" id="switch-label1" data-yes="YES" data-no="NO"></span><span class="switch-handle"></span>
    </label>
          </label>
          <label><h3>Notification 2</h3>
    <label class="switch switch-left-right">
    <input class="switch-input" id="switch-input2" type="checkbox"/>
    <span class="switch-label" id="switch-label2" data-yes="YES" data-no="NO"></span><span class="switch-handle"></span>
    </label>
          </label>
        </center>
      </section>
      <center>
        <table id="box-table-a">
          <thead>
            <tr style="border-left: 4px solid #aabcfe; border-right: 4px solid #aabcfe;">
              <th>Notification 1</th>
              <th>Notification 2</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr style="border-left: 4px solid #aabcfe; border-right: 4px solid #aabcfe;">
              <td id="status-1">No</td>
              <td id="status-2">No</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Anurag ... this relly works.. but when i save to file it do not get the same output. may be i am missing out something.

Answer (score 0):

Remove change event function call and 
your function is wrong it should be

```
 $('.switch-input').on('change', function() {
          var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
          var selectedData;
          var $switchLabel = $('.switch-label');
          console.log('isChecked: ' + isChecked); 

          if(isChecked) {
            selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-yes');
          } else {
            selectedData = $switchLabel.attr('data-no');
          }
          console.log('Selected data: ' + selectedData);
});
```

Refer [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1e21jztk/)

Comment: am getting this as output on toggle isChecked: true
(index):270 Selected data: YES
(index):263 isChecked: false
(index):270 Selected data: NO

Comment: i am also able to get the output in console log.my first aim is to get the value displayed in same page in respective table according to the switch selected. to understand whether my selected value is Yes or no of Toggle 1 and 2,

Comment: i have updated code .... added 1 more console to get which notification you are changing ... hope this helps